# How to change java-ME keyboard input

Tags: java-me, keyboard

I am trying to change keyboard type for `TextField` component. I know that the keyboard type can be changed using `setConstraint` on the `TextField`, e.g. `TextField.DECIMAL` will change the keyboard as decimal input and `TextField.ANY` will change the keyboard to normal keyboard.

Now, what I want is to explicitly change the keyboard type itself without changing the constraint of `TextField`. Is it possible to do it? Which class that has responsibility to control keyboard behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Is it not possible, at least not when you use standard TextField and build-in keyboard.

The Java-ME Standard supports a wide range of different hardware, touchscreen, keypad, qwerty-keyboards of lot of different types. 
The standard just makes no assumption about available keyboards.
You can only give hints (like DECIMAL), and the platform is responsible to give you the best possible way to input your data.

If you really, really need it, you need to implement the keyboard yourself, (or use some third party UI-library like LWUIT to do this). But than you need also handle different languages yourself. And the keyboard will look different than the native one. So I can recommend it only to experienced Java-Me developers.

Comment: I was thinking perhaps there is a class named KeyboardSetting or something similar deep inside the bowel of JavaME to set the keyboard constraint. But apparently, there is no such thing. I couldn't find it at least.